# Kotlin load html from internal storage to webview

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, android-internal-storage

i would like to load an html page from my internal storage into a webview but i couldn't find any exemple on how to do it. Here is what i can do :

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/article_0028_0071.html")
```

This work but i had to manually add the page to asset. Then i got the same file in internal storage the full path is : /data/user/0/com.example.app/files/articles/article_0028_0071.html
So i have tried :

```
path = "/data/user/0/com.example.app/files/articles/article_0028_0071.html"
webView.loadUrl(path)
```

This give me no error but a blanc page. also tried with "file:///articles/article_0028_0071.html" but same result no error blanc page.

So i would like to know how should i write the path to access html from internal storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add file:/// before your path.

```
path = "file:///data/user/0/com.example.app/files/articles/article_0028_0071.html"
webView.loadUrl(path)
```

This work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

you can handle every type of url as you wish just set up your webview via customized WebViewClient

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
            if (url.startWith("file:")) {                     
                //do whatever you need
                }
                return false;
            }else if(url.startWith("http"){....etc
```